# in the same order/in the reverse order

Tags: phrase-usage

I don't understand how to use these two phrases. Are we only allowed to put a noun after "in the same order/reverse order"? Or can I put something other than nouns?

- Eat candies in the same order as my mom usually eats.
- Eat candies in the reverse order of  (I don't know what comes next...)

I can't think of good examples, so it would be great if you could give me some good examples.

Comment: Please explain using as many words as necessary exactly what you want your sentence to mean. Without that, I have no idea what "the order of eating candies" means. If you eat two sweets, you eat the first one before the second, but it doesn't make sense to "reverse" the order and eat the second one before the first. (Which would be impossible anyway, if your mom has already eaten both! :)

Comment: One good way to see what sorts of things come after a particular phrase is to [put it in Google’s ngram viewer with an asterisk after it](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+reverse+order+of+*&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) then read some of the excerpts to get a feel for how the phrase is used. I like to limit the search to more recent books (like 1970 and after).

Comment: Eat candies in the reverse order of (my mom's habit). The preposition *of* expects to introduce a noun, yes. The linking word *as* expects to introduce a parallel word - *Eat* (verb) and mom *eats* (verb).

Comment: @FumbleFingers One possibility is that mum eats the red ones first then the blue ones and so on. Think M&Ms (Smarties) or any of the chocolate assortments.

Answer (score 1):

"**In the same order**" and "**in the reverse order**" can be used with different parts of speech to indicate the sequence of actions or arrangement of items. In the examples below, you can see some examples, including using them with nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, and prepositional phrases to convey instructions or describe actions:

**With Nouns:**

- "Write the countries' names in the same order as they appear on the map."
- "Arrange the books on the shelf in reverse order according to their publication dates."

**With Verbs:**

- "Complete the tasks in the same order as listed on the checklist."
- "Read the paragraphs aloud in reverse order to assess coherence."

**With Adjectives:**

- "Paint the rooms in the same order as their previous colors."
- "List the items in reverse order of importance."

**With Adverbs:**

- "Follow the instructions in the same order as presented in the manual."
- "Operate the machinery in reverse order, ensuring careful attention to prevent accidents."

**With Prepositional Phrases:**

- "Arrange the documents on the table in the same order as they're sorted in the file."
- "Line up the chairs in reverse order from their arrangement for the meeting."

Comment: Handsome presentation. The examples for adjectives and adverb appear to all use nouns.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways of using "the same X as". It can be followed by a noun ("the same order as my mom"), prepositional phrase ("the same order as in America"), time phrase ("the same order as yesterday"), clause ("the same order as my mom eats"), or others.

I'd rephrase the "same" example slightly, because I prefer "them" on the end, although the choice is yours. If you start with:

> I eat candies in the same order as my mom usually eats them.

and want to reverse it to say you eat in the opposite order, there are a number of different ways. You could use "to", "of", "from" or no preposition, or another phrase to link them. The Corpus of Contemporary American English suggests that "of" is overwhelmingly the most common, although usually it is followed by a simple noun or short noun phrase. If using a longer clause or phrase after, the construction often becomes unwieldy and confusing.

If using a preposition you need to convert the clause "my mom usually eats (them)" into some kind of noun phrase. This could be done using "the reverse order to *the order that my mom usually eats*" or "the reverse order of *the way that my mom usually eats*" or more colloquially "the reverse order of *how my mom usually eats*"

Some examples from the Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA). One is with no preposition or other connector:

> We leave pines, birches, and larches in the reverse order we saw them on our way in

So you could have:

> I eat candies in the reverse order mom usually eats them.

You can also explicitly indicate a comparison with a phrase like "in comparison with" or "relative to" (and often a WH-word). COCA example:

> a reverse order relative to what happened globally

But this would give a rather long sentence such as:

> I eat candies in the reverse order in comparison with how my mother usually eats them.

Here's a clause with "from":

> All the other conveyances are drawn up in the reverse order from that in which they arrived

So that would give:

> I eat candies in the reverse order from that in which my mother usually eats them.

One of the most common is with "of", usually just with a noun or noun phrase:

> In reverse order of greatness

> The remaining teams were slotted in reverse order of finish

> The 12 excerpts contained in DVD 2 were in reverse order of excerpts on DVD 1

> During the career-compromise process, occupations are eliminated in reverse order of their acquisition

You could adapt this to something like:

> I eat candies in the reverse order of how my mother usually eats them.

Although "to" is just as natural:

> I eat candies in the reverse order to how my mother usually eats them.

So in summary there are a lot of ways of using "reverse order", including with no preposition or conjunction, but if you have a preposition it must be followed by a noun phrase.

Comment: Your explanation really helped me. Thank you so much!